# How to measure view or view group inflating time in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-view, android-inflate

I am looking for utility or any way how can I measure the time required for inflater to inflate some portion (view or viewgroup or whole screen) in Android.

I know there is default feature in debug mode that shows overdraw, but I need to have measure the time taken to inflate view.

What is the best way to do this. 
Thx.

Comment: What are you need it for?

Comment: To improve performance

Answer (score 4):

Check out [lucasr/probe](https://github.com/lucasr/probe/). Here is a [blog post](https://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2015/05/06/custom-viewgroups/) by a Facebook engineer on improving view measure time.

[Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html) is also a useful visual tool to see which part of your layout can be improved.

Answer (score 3):

In 2019, you can use android x benchmark library easy for benchmark inflate time.
[android doc write-benchmark](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/benchmark.md#write-benchmark)

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ViewBenchmark {
    @get:Rule
    val benchmarkRule = BenchmarkRule()

    @Test
    fun simpleViewInflate() {
        val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val root = FrameLayout(context)

        benchmarkRule.keepRunning {
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_simple_view, root, false)
        }
    }
}
```

or you can use system trace to benchmark only inflate layout code

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, you have androidx.benchmark library where you can measure layout inflation time. Check out the sample code here from Google. https://github.com/android/performance-samples

[ViewInflateBenchmark.kt](https://github.com/android/performance-samples/blob/main/BenchmarkSample/microbenchmark/src/androidTest/java/com/example/benchmark/ViewInflateBenchmark.kt)

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ViewInflateBenchmark {

    @get:Rule
    val benchmarkRule = BenchmarkRule()

    @Test
    fun benchmarkViewInflate() {
        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val root = FrameLayout(context)

        benchmarkRule.measureRepeated {
            val inflated = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_card, root, false)
        }
    }
}
```